# How to strikethrough a specific text in textview with some angle

Tags: android, html, textview, spannablestring

[I want to achieve this my textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO5Hv.jpg)

I want to strikethrough through a specific text in a textview with some angle as show in the imAGE attached. How to achieve this android. I tried to do it with HTML.fromhtml method but all the tag (like "hr" ) is not working in textview.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568#7657) for different spans possible.

And this is developer documentation for [dynamic drawable span](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/DynamicDrawableSpan).